# Create my own SoundCloud iOS Login Screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, authentication, soundcloud

I already have an iOS App for SoundCloud. The official iOS SDK from SoundCloud isn't very up-to-date and so I wanted to create my own login ViewController with a username and password textfield. Now I'm using the mobile version of the login web page, which is opened in mobile Safari when the user taps the login button.

As I said, am I allowed to create my own ViewController which allows the user to login to SoundCloud, without opening Safari with the login web page?

I would be very thankful if someone could answer my question very soon, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am using SoundCloud in my app as well. As you said oficial library is not very up-to-date so I decided to create my own library:

[ABMSoundCloudAPI on Github](https://github.com/andresbrun/ABMSoundCloudAPI)

Where in the end I decided to use an internal webview to present login/singup soundcloud webpage and manage the output (code or error). Maybe it could be interesting for you.

Comment: I think you mean it "isn't" very up-to-date. Looks good, but I think I don't need it any more, sorry :/
I just wanted to know if I'm allowed to create my own login view, but even the developers from SoundCloud are to ignorant to answer my question.